Can KMDF driver check if an IOCTL came from an admin user-mode process?
I'm playing with a KMDF (kernel mode) sample driver that came with VS 2022.
I've added the following code to process IOCTL in my Queue.c:
VOID
TestEvtIoDeviceControl(
    _In_ WDFQUEUE Queue,
    _In_ WDFREQUEST Request,
    _In_ size_t OutputBufferLength,
    _In_ size_t InputBufferLength,
    _In_ ULONG IoControlCode
    )
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

    if(IoControlCode == IOCTL_MY_TEST)
    {
            REQ_TEST* pReq = NULL;
            size_t szcbRead = 0;
            status = WdfRequestRetrieveInputBuffer(Request, sizeof(*pReq), &pReq, &szcbRead);
            if(NT_SUCCESS(status) &&
                 szcbRead == sizeof(*pReq))
            {
                //Process data received in pReq ...

            }
    }

    WdfRequestComplete(Request, status);
}

where:
#define IOCTL_MY_TEST CTL_CODE(0x8000, 0x800, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)

typedef struct _REQ_TEST
{
    ULONG Param1;
    int Param2;
}REQ_TEST, *PREQ_TEST;

The question is - can I find out if the user-mode process sending my IOCTL_MY_TEST IOCTL is running as a member of the built-in admin group, and if not prevent processing of this IOCTL request?

I haven't played with IOCTLs in a while but if I recall correctly, your dispatch gets called in the context of the process who made the request.
You can easily test that theory by calling PsGetCurrentProcessId and check what kind of user created it or calling ZwQueryInformationProcess(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,ProcessImageFileName,...)) to get it's path.
From what I've seen in other usermode-process-bound drivers, you traditionally do this check more within IRP_MJ_CREATE in which if the process doesn't match your criteria, you can return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED to prevent further communication.
Be wary of how you implement that check as this is one of the principal way people gain unauthorized access to the kernel (see article)

Thanks. I was actually asking about KMDF driver that is using WDF framework. Since I asked, I found out that it seems like the acceptable way to do this is via the .inf file for the driver. Although I'm still not sure about the details. I got sidetracked by some other project.

I'm not that knowledgeable about WDF framework so I cannot give you a knowledgeable answer. My guess is that just putting that requirement in the .inf file that you ship with your driver wouldn't prevent anyone for modifying it but I have never used one before so I wouldn't know... I reckon that editing the question to mention the WDF so you can get a more precise answer if you are still looking for one :)
